# How to create multiple card views without copy pasting

Tags: django, html, django-templates, django-views

Im currently creating a website which shows tv series and movies, I've so far created a cardview which shows only one movie and i obviously want to add more which is where my dilemma is. Is there a way to create more than one cardview in HTML without having to copy and paste a bunch of times?

Here is my parent class in Django;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% if title %}
      <title> {{ Flix | title }} </title>
    {% else %}
      <title> Flix </title>
    {% endif %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/Css/Parent.css">
  </head>
  <div class="CardView">
      <img src= '{% block Images %}{% endblock %}' alt="">
        <h5> {% block MovieInfo %}{% endblock MovieInfo %} </h4>
  </div>
  <body>
    </div class="mainContent">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the HomePage where the movies are displayed;

```
{% extends "Movies/Parent.html" %}

{% block Images %}
  {% for Movie in Movies %}
    {{ Movie.Image }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock Images %}

{% block MovieInfo %}
  {% for Movie in Movies %}
      <h5> {{ Movie.Name }} </h5>
      <h5> Rating: {{ Movie.Rating }}</h5>
      <h5> Date: {{ Movie.Date_Posted }} </h5>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock MovieInfo %}

{% block MovieName %}
    {% for Movie in Movies %}
      <h4> {{ Movie.Name }} </h4>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock MovieName %}
```

And here is where the Movie information is being returned as well as the location of the movie image;

```
GivenMovies = [
    {
        'Image': 'static/Images/MovieImages/Thor.png',
        'Name': 'Thor',
        'Genre': 'Action',
        'Rating': '7.0',
        'Content': 'Mad Movie',
        'Date_Posted': 'January 18, 2017'
    },
    {
        'Image': 'static/Images/MovieImages/Constantine.jpg',
        'Name': 'Constantine',
        'Genre': 'Action, Sci-Fi',
        'Rating': '7.2',
        'Content': 'Another madness of a movie',
        'Date_Posted': 'January 18, 2015'
    }
]

def MainPage(request):
    AllMovies = {'Movies': GivenMovies}
    return render(request, 'Movies/HomePage.html', AllMovies)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: After looking at your code again, I think you have it right up to the blocks. I would change it to something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% if title %}
      <title> {{ Flix | title }} </title>
    {% else %}
      <title> Flix </title>
    {% endif %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/Css/Parent.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    </div class="mainContent">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Absolutely! This is a huge part of django. You will need to use a for loop in your HTML.

```
{% block content %}
{% for movie in Movies %}

<div>
     <div class="CardView"> #all card HTML in here
         <img src= '{{ movie.Image }}' alt="">
         <h5> {{ movie.Name }}  </h5>
         <h5> {{ movie.Genre }}  </h5>
         <h5> {{ movie.Rating }}  </h5>
         <h5> {{ movie.Content }}  </h5>
         <h5> {{ movie.Date_Posted }}  </h5>           
     </div>  
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

You may have to move some HTML tags around to get what you want but thats the basic idea! Good luck!

Comment: No problem! Good luck!